# Iterate Over Rows, Ask for Input for Items Over 0, Store Responses

Tags: python, pandas, input

I have a simple DF, that I used groupby and sum to clean up.  Now I want to iterate over each row and if the orderqty has a value >0, ask the user "How Many of this item {name of item} were we allocated?" and then store this response.

The stored response needs to keep the itmdesc (name of item).  The goal is to iterate over the ungrouped dataframe later and create a new column for each row by dividing the existing number by the stored response number.

Sample DF and Code:
Clearly this code doesn't work but I am feeling pretty lost about combining the input with iterrows.  I have gotten a myriad of error, the current one being **'str' object not callable.**

Thank you in advance.

```
for i, row in sums.iterrows():
      if sums.orderqty > 0:    
      num = int(input("How many (row.itmdesc[i]) were we allocated?"))
```

```
    orderqty
itmdesc 
ALCATEL 1X EVOLVE   72
ALCATEL 3V  50
ALCATEL 7   0
ALCATEL GO FLIP 0
ALCATEL GO FLIP 3   28
ALCATEL JOY TAB 53
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? 1.0 handles strings differently.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please add your sample data as text in your question, not as a picture so that it makes a [mcve] we can reproduce

Comment: @G.Anderson - Fixed? Let me know if that works?

Comment: @scottsaenz  - Pandas 0.24.2

Comment: It would be better if you had the data listed in a consumable format,
`Data = {'Product': ['Desktop Computer','Tablet','iPhone','Laptop'],
        'Price': [700,250,800,1200]
        }
df = DataFrame(Data, columns= ['Product', 'Price'])
`
https://datatofish.com/export-pandas-dataframe-json/

Comment: Can you share what the DataFrame looks like before, and the expected output? As an aside, be careful of `.iterrows()`. Explicit loops should be a last resort, and `.iterrows()` is particularly bad.

Answer (score 0):

I can see right off the back that your third line needs to be indented. also if you are going to iterate through two objects simultaneously you need to use the zip() function normally. I normally don't use .iterrows for iterating through tables and I like to do the following;

## this takes you through all cols and all rows in each col, you can also iterate through the index or the range(len(df)), this will give you a num that you can use with df.iloc[rownum,colnum]

```
for i in df:
    print(i)
    for j in df[i]:
        print(i,j)
```

also list generators might help if you get to slowed and detailed.

they follow the general syntax below and can be nested;

```
obj = [i if i > 0 else 0 for i in iterable]
```

Edit: also I think there is a major problem with your string being turned into an int. You cannot convert that whole string to an int which is what it seems like you're doing

Comment: Can you explain where zip would be involved here?

Comment: You need to zip two things together to iterate through them. so here you'd do something like; for i , j in zip(df.index,df.columns):                                                       You probably will not need it as it is more for iterating through two things simultaneously. you seem to just need to iterate through the rows

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually very simple. Iterate over rows, store responses as list and then add the list as a column to the Dataframe afterward. The types were not the same, so I needed to change the types and then I could perform the math in a new column as needed.  Maybe a cleaner way to do this later when I refactor everything, but up and running for now!  Thank you, everyone.

```
allocations= []
for i, j in sums.iterrows():
    answer = input(f"How much of {i} were we allocated?")
    allocations.append(answer)

sums['allocation'] = allocations
sums = sums.astype({'orderqty':float,'allocation':float})
sums['order_percent'] = sums['orderqty']/sums['allocation']
```